# Synchronizing processes with semaphores and signals in C

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, signals, semaphore

I have to write program in C on Linux. It has to have 3 processes - first reads from STDIN, sends message through FIFO to second process, which counts lenght of recevied message and sends result to third process (also through FIFO), which displays it on STDOUT. I have to synchronize it using semaphores. Also I have to add signal handling (which I am doing using shared memory) - one signal to end program, second to stop it, third to resume. Signal can be send to any of the processes. I have some code already, but it's not working as it should.

First problem is with synchronization - as you can see by running it, first message is received by second process, but then it stuck. First and second processes are showing their messages, but not the third one. There are very similar, so it's confusing. I have to send another message, then P3 is showing the length of previous one.

Second problem is with signals - after sending one, I have to press enter (for SIGUSR) or send message (for SIGINT) for it to be served.

Any ideas what's wrong? There are some improvements from what I posted before, but it's still not working properly and I don't have much time to finish it (till monday). I know it's a lot of code, but if someone could just analyze communication of second and third process, I will be very grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define WRITE 1
#define READ 0
#define MEM_ID 1
#define MEM_SIZE 1

#define OK  "[ \033[1;32mOK\033[0m ]\n"
#define ERR "[\033[1;31mFAIL\033[0m] "
#define SIGNAL "\033[1;33m\033[5m>> SIGNAL <<\033[0m\n"

#define S1 SIGINT
#define S2 SIGUSR1
#define S3 SIGUSR2
#define S4 SIGCONT

/* union semun - from POSIX specification for semctl() */
/* NB: on Mac OS X, and apparently in defiance of POSIX, <sys/sem.h> declares union semun */
/*
union semun
{
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    unsigned short  *array;
} arg;
*/

/*
union semun
{
    int val;
    ushort *array;
};
*/

int process1(void);
int process2(void);
int process3(void);
void signal_callback(int signo);
//void signal_handling(int snd, int rcv);   // JL
void signal_handling(void);     // JL
void sem_down(int semid, int semnum);
void sem_up(int semid, int semnum);

char work = 1, quit = 0;
char inter_snd = 0, inter_rcv = 0;
struct sembuf semstruct;
int sem23, sem12, mem;
char *message;
int res[3];

static const char *fifoname[] = { "1fifo2", "2fifo3" };

static
void main_quit(int n)
{
    printf("%s(): signal %d\n", __func__, n);  // JL
    kill(res[0], S1);
}

int main(void)
{
    //union semun arg;  // JL
    printf("[G] Launching\n");

    signal(SIGINT, main_quit);
    signal(SIGTERM, main_quit);
    // creating FIFO
    printf("[G] Creating FIFO... ");
    res[0] = mkfifo(fifoname[0], 0644);
    res[1] = mkfifo(fifoname[1], 0644);
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1))
    {
        perror(ERR);
        unlink(fifoname[0]);
        unlink(fifoname[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf(OK);

    // create two semaphores and set values
    printf("[G] Creating semaphores... ");
    sem12 = semget(READ, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    sem23 = semget(WRITE, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0644);

    if ((sem23 == -1) || (sem12 == -1))
    {
        perror(ERR);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf(OK);

    printf("[G] Initializing semaphores values... ");
    semctl(sem12, 0, SETVAL, 0);
    semctl(sem12, 1, SETVAL, 1);
    semctl(sem23, 0, SETVAL, 0);
    semctl(sem23, 1, SETVAL, 1);
    printf(OK);

    // creating shared memory
    printf("[G] Reserving shared memory... ");
    mem = shmget(MEM_ID, MEM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    message = (char *)shmat(mem, 0, 0);

    if (mem == -1)
    {
        perror(ERR);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf(OK);

    if ((res[0] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        process1();
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((res[1] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        process2();
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((res[2] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        process3();
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("[G] Building process tree... ");
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1) || (res[2] == -1))
    {
        perror(ERR);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf(OK);
        printf("[G] P1[pid]: %d, P2[pid]: %d, P3[pid]: %d\n", res[0], res[1], res[2]);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);

    printf("[G] Deleting FIFO... ");
    res[0] = unlink(fifoname[0]);
    res[1] = unlink(fifoname[1]);
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1))
        perror(ERR);
    else
        printf(OK);

    printf("[G] Freeing shared memory... ");
    res[0] = shmdt((char *)message);
    res[1] = shmctl(mem, IPC_RMID, 0);
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1))
        perror(ERR);
    else
        printf(OK);

    printf("[G] Deleting semaphores... ");
    res[0] = semctl(sem23, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
    res[1] = semctl(sem12, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1))
        perror(ERR);
    else
        printf(OK);

    printf("[G] Ending...\n");
    return 0;
}

int process1(void)
{
    char tab[100];
    FILE *fifoh;

    signal(S1, signal_callback);
    signal(S2, signal_callback);
    signal(S3, signal_callback);
    signal(S4, signal_callback);

    fifoh = fopen(fifoname[0], "w");
    setbuf(fifoh, NULL);

    printf("[P1] Ready.\n");
    //while (fgets(tab, sizeof(tab), stdin) > 0)    // JL
    while (fgets(tab, sizeof(tab), stdin) != 0)     // JL
    {
        if (work)
        {
            sem_down(sem12, WRITE);
            printf("[P1] Sending: %s", tab);
            fprintf(fifoh, "%s\n", tab);
            sem_up(sem12, READ);
        }
        //signal_handling(inter_snd, inter_rcv);    // JL
        signal_handling();  // JL
    }
    fclose(fifoh);
    printf("[P1] Ending...\n");
    return 0;
}

int process2(void)
{
    char tab[100];
    FILE *fifo_in, *fifo_out;

    printf("[P2] Ready.\n");

    fifo_in = fopen(fifoname[0], "r");
    fifo_out = fopen(fifoname[1], "w");

    setbuf(fifo_out, NULL);
    setbuf(fifo_in, NULL);

    signal(S1, signal_callback);
    signal(S2, signal_callback);
    signal(S3, signal_callback);
    signal(S4, signal_callback);

    do
    {
        if (work)
        {
            sem_down(sem12, READ);
            fscanf(fifo_in, "%s", (char *)tab);
            sem_up(sem12, WRITE);
            printf("[P2] Received \"%s\" with length %zu.\n", tab, strlen(tab));
            sem_down(sem23, WRITE);
            fprintf(fifo_out, "%d\n", (int)strlen(tab));
            sem_up(sem23, READ);
        }
        //signal_handling(inter_snd, inter_rcv);    // JL
        signal_handling();  // JL
    } while (!quit);

    fclose(fifo_in);
    fclose(fifo_out);
    printf("[P2] Ending...\n");
    return 0;
}

int process3(void)
{
    FILE *fifo_in;
    int count;

    printf("[P3] Ready.\n");

    signal(S1, signal_callback);
    signal(S2, signal_callback);
    signal(S3, signal_callback);
    signal(S4, signal_callback);

    fifo_in = fopen(fifoname[1], "r");
    setbuf(fifo_in, NULL);

    do
    {
        if (work)
        {
            sem_down(sem23, READ);
            fscanf(fifo_in, "%d\n", (int *)&count);
            sem_up(sem23, WRITE);
            printf("[P3] Received: %d characters.\n", count);
        }
        //signal_handling(inter_snd, inter_rcv);    // JL
        signal_handling();  // JL
    } while (!quit);
    fclose(fifo_in);
    printf("[P3] Ending...\n");
    return 0;
}

//void signal_handling(int snd, int rvc)
void signal_handling(void)
{
    if (inter_snd > 0)
    {
        printf("Signal received...\n");

        semstruct.sem_op = -3;
        semop(sem23, &semstruct, 1);

        *message = inter_snd;
        inter_snd = 0;

        semstruct.sem_op = 3;
        semop(sem12, &semstruct, 1);

        printf("Sending to other processes\n");
        kill(0, S4);
    }
    if (inter_rcv)
    {
        inter_rcv = 0;

        semstruct.sem_op = -1;
        semop(sem12, &semstruct, 1);

        switch (*message)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Quitting...\n");
            quit = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Stopping...\n");
            work = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Starting...\n");
            work = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("There's garbage in memory :/..\n");
        }
        semstruct.sem_op = 1;
        semop(sem23, &semstruct, 1);
    }
}

void signal_callback(int signo)
{
    printf(SIGNAL);
    switch (signo)
    {
    case S1:
        inter_snd = 1;
        break;
    case S2:
        inter_snd = 2;
        break;
    case S3:
        inter_snd = 3;
        break;
    case S4:
        inter_rcv = 1;
        break;
    }
}

void sem_down(int semid, int semnum)
{
    semstruct.sem_flg = 0;
    semstruct.sem_num = semnum;
    semstruct.sem_op = -1;
    do
    {
        errno = 0;
        semop(semid, &semstruct, 1);
    } while (errno == EINTR);
}

void sem_up(int semid, int semnum)
{
    semstruct.sem_flg = 0;

    semstruct.sem_num = semnum;
    semstruct.sem_op = 1;
    semop(semid, &semstruct, 1);
}
```

Expected behaviour:

```
[P3] Ready.
[P2] Ready.
[P1] Ready.
asd
[P1] Sending: asd
[P2] Received "asd" with length 3.
[P3] Received: 3 characters.
as
[P1] Sending: as
[P2] Received "as" with length 2.
[P3] Received: 2 characters.
```

Signals:

Signal should be recieved and sent to every other processes. What happens next is specified in singnal_handling. Every process should show their message (Quitting/Stopping/etc).

Actual behaviour:

```
[P3] Ready.
[P2] Ready.
[P1] Ready.
asd 
[P1] Sending: asd
[P2] Received "asd" with length 3.
dd
[P1] Sending: dd
[P2] Received "dd" with length 2.
[P3] Received: 3 characters. //first message
as
[P1] Sending: as
[P2] Received "as" with length 2.
[P3] Received: 2 characters. //second
asd
[P1] Sending: asd
[P2] Received "asd" with length 3.
[P3] Received: 2 characters. // third
```

And with signals, well... I figured out that after SIGINT I could send message, hit enter twice and then I got expected behaviour (quitting program). Pressing enter also works when I'm sending another signals:

```
$ kill -s SIGUSR1 2900
$ kill -s SIGUSR2 2900
```

Gives:

```
asd
[P1] Sending: asd
[P2] Received "asd" with length 3.
[P3] Received: 3 characters.
Signal received...
Sending to other processes
>> SIGNAL <<
Stopping...
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
Signal received...
Sending to other processes
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
Starting...

[P1] Sending: 
Starting...
asd
[P1] Sending: asd
[P2] Received "asd" with length 3.
Starting...
[P3] Received: 3 characters.
```

So again - after sending a signal I have to send a message for it to be handled. So, it's kinda working. But very, very bad.

Comment: The first step in getting help is to provide compilable code. This code attempts to define a function `main_quit()` inside `main()`

Comment: It's compilable. It's working, you can check if you want.

Comment: Ah, ok, it's a gcc extension. Nvm (although I wouldn't really do it because of portability issues)

Comment: Well, I guess you're right, so I added a quick (temporary) fix.

Comment: I just tried to compile it on ubuntu linux 14.04 with gcc,  The result of the compile is 10 warnings, some of which are very critical, such as when #include'ing ipc.h, must #define _SVID_SOURCE or #define _XOPEN_SOURCE. and passing a size_t (a long int) where a int should be used and incorrect types for semaphore creation (sem_t), returned value from fork() (pid_t).  Using the res[] array for two totally different purposes.

Comment: for debugging, strongly suggest starting with a minimal working code, without signals, without semaphores.   When that works, then add semaphores, then add signals.    Otherwise, you have left yourself with a massive debugging problem.   Strongly suggest using gdb (or similar utility) to step through each execution thread to determine exactly where the code is 'hanging'

Comment: regarding this comment: "It's compilable. It's working, you can check if you want."   It doesn't cleanly compile and needs numerous corrections in the source.  If it were working, you would not be asking help to get it to work.  Suggest 1) fixing the warnings 2) strip the signal and semaphore code (they can just be commented out) 3) use a debugger to pinpoint the source of the problem. 4) fix the problem, then, one by one, add in the semaphore and signal code.

Comment: BTW:  'ushort' is not defined in any of the code nor included headers.  perhaps you meant 'unsigned short'

Comment: fscanf() will stop when it encounters any 'white space' AND will not continue until that white space is consumed.   suggest using a different method of reading the characters from the fifo files

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't have any warnings. I'm using Linux Mint 16. Here's how it looks in my case: http://i58.tinypic.com/4hyrh5.jpg

Comment: Even with -Wall option I have just one warning about unused variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your code verbatim onto a Mac running Mac OS X 10.10.3, using GCC 5.1.0, using the standard compilation options I use for compiling code from Stack Overflow, I get compilation warnings as shown (I called your code `semshm.c`):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror semshm.c -o semshm
semshm.c:29:7: error: redefinition of ‘union semun’
 union semun {
       ^
In file included from semshm.c:8:0:
/usr/include/sys/sem.h:176:7: note: originally defined here
 union semun {
       ^
semshm.c:48:6: error: no previous prototype for ‘main_quit’ [-Werror=missing-prototypes]
 void main_quit(int n) {
      ^
semshm.c: In function ‘main_quit’:
semshm.c:48:20: error: unused parameter ‘n’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 void main_quit(int n) {
                    ^
semshm.c: In function ‘main’:
semshm.c:54:17: error: unused variable ‘arg’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     union semun arg;
                 ^
semshm.c: In function ‘process1’:
semshm.c:161:43: error: ordered comparison of pointer with integer zero [-Werror=extra]
     while (fgets(tab, sizeof(tab), stdin) > 0) {
                                           ^
semshm.c: In function ‘process2’:
semshm.c:197:20: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Werror=format=]
             printf("[P2] Recieved \"%s\" with length %d.\n", tab, strlen(tab));
                    ^
semshm.c:197:20: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Werror=format=]
semshm.c: In function ‘signal_handling’:
semshm.c:239:26: error: unused parameter ‘snd’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 void signal_handling(int snd, int rvc) {
                          ^
semshm.c:239:35: error: unused parameter ‘rvc’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 void signal_handling(int snd, int rvc) {
                                   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The first problem is peculiar to Mac OS X; it seems to define `union semun` in `<sys/sem.h>` despite the POSIX specification for [`semctl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html)
saying explicitly:

> The *semctl()* function provides a variety of semaphore control operations as specified by *cmd*. The fourth argument is optional and depends upon the operation requested. If required, it is of type **union semun**, which the application shall explicitly declare:
>
> ```
> union semun {
>     int val;
>     struct semid_ds *buf;
>     unsigned short  *array;
> } arg;
> ```

The only excuse for the POSIX requirement is bad historical precedent, which Mac OS X has over-ridden.  So, the double declaration of `struct semun` is not held against you.  It is curious that POSIX requires an extra member, though, compared with what you specify.  Anyway, I commented out that declaration to get past that.

There are other warnings, though many of them are not all that serious.  Unused variables are not good, but not hugely harmful.  The format mismatch between `%d` and `size_t` matters if, as on my machine, `%d` looks for a 32-bit value and `size_t` is a 64-bit quantity.  The test for `fgets()` should be `!= 0`; it returns NULL (or 0 — I use 0 too) on failure.

The most curious problem is the unused arguments to `signal_handling()`.  The calls pass the global variables `inter_snd` and `inter_rcv` to the function, but the function ignores those values and simply manipulates the global variables.  There is at least a serious disconnect between the calling and called code here.

For the purposes of getting on with life, I converted `signal_handling()` to a parameterless function `void signal_handling(void);` and left its body unchanged (but fixed all the calls to it).  I added:

```
printf("%s(): signal %d\n", __func__, n);
```

to `main_quit()` in defiance of the advice on [how to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019).  I also fixed the *'i' before 'e' except after 'c'* spelling mistakes.  Also 'quitting' has two t's and 'stopping' has two p's — English is such a weird language.

Finally, I extracted the two FIFO names (`1fifo2` and `2fifo3`) into an array:

```
static const char *fifoname[] = { "1fifo2", "2fifo3" };
```

and used either `fifoname[0]` or `fifoname[1]` in place of the literals.  Repeated file name literals are a bad idea.  I also used the new names to clean up (`unlink(fifoname[0]); unlink(fifoname[1]);`) the FIFOs if either existed after failing to create them.

- Despite the collection of warnings, the code is not bad; few programs pass that set of options unscathed without some editing to make it pass cleanly.

With the code compiled, I ran it a few times.  One of the last runs was:

```
$ ./semshm
[G] Launching
[G] Creating FIFO... [ OK ]
[G] Creating semaphores... [ OK ]
[G] Initializing semaphores values... [ OK ]
[G] Reserving shared memory... [ OK ]
[G] Building process tree... [ OK ]
[G] P1[pid]: 36030, P2[pid]: 36031, P3[pid]: 36032
[P2] Ready.
[P1] Ready.
[P3] Ready.
^C>> SIGNAL <<
main_quit(): signal 2
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
absolute baloney
[P1] Sending: absolute baloney
Signal received...
[P2] Received "absolute" with length 8.
Signal received...
commestible goods for everyone
^C>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
main_quit(): signal 2
>> SIGNAL <<
Sending to other processes
>> SIGNAL <<
Sending to other processes
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
Quitting...
>> SIGNAL <<
Quitting...
[P2] Ending...
[P3] Received: 8 characters.
Signal received...
Sending to other processes
>> SIGNAL <<
>> SIGNAL <<
Quitting...
>> SIGNAL <<
[P3] Ending...
^\Quit: 3
$
```

I typed an interrupt, which was handled.  I typed 'absolute baloney', of which the 'absolute' part was apparently received in one place, but the 'baloney' part never made it. That's puzzling.  I typed 'commestible goods for everyone' and to all appearances, it was completely ignored.  I tried another interrupt, which apparently interrupted things.  I tried control-D (EOF), which apparently did nothing.  I used control-backslash (<kbd>control-\</kbd>) to generate a quit signal, which did indeed stop the program.  I'd done that before; reruns showed the wisdom of cleaning up after spotting that the FIFOs were already created as I got the failure message, then reran the code and it worked OK.  The output shows green OK messages, and flashing yellow-ish `>>> SIGNAL <<<` messages.

So, you didn't tell us how to use the program, or the output to expect from it.

Your 'no compiler warnings' assertion was a little optimistic, but not too far off the truth.

Now you need to upgrade the question to specify/illustrate the inputs you give it and the expected behaviour from that input and to show the unexpected behaviour you actually get from it.

#### One semi-working version of `semshm.c`

This is the 'as compiled', partially annotated code that I compiled and ran.  To compile it on Linux or other more accurately POSIX-compliant platform (more accurate than Mac OS X, that is), you'll need to uncomment one of the `union semun` blocks.  I'd normally remove `<sys/types.h>` (modern POSIX almost never requires you to include it; older versions from the last millennium did require it — see [POSIX 1997](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/) which did, but compare with [POSIX 2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) which did not).

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> ```
>
> …code co-opted into question…see revision 3 at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30813144/revisions…
>
> …I ran over the 30,000 character limit with this code on board…
>
> ```
> }
> ```

#### Another mostly working version of `semshm.c`

Taking the extra information about how the code is supposed to be working, and putting in a lot of extra diagnostic printing, and observing that process 2 and 3 get stuck waiting on a semaphore which is not signalled, I came up with this variant of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define WRITE 1
#define READ 0
#define MEM_ID 1
#define MEM_SIZE 1

#define OK  "[ \033[1;32mOK\033[0m ]\n"
#define ERR "[\033[1;31mFAIL\033[0m] "
#define SIGNAL "\033[1;33m\033[5m>> SIGNAL <<\033[0m\n"

#define S1 SIGINT
#define S2 SIGUSR1
#define S3 SIGUSR2
#define S4 SIGCONT

int process1(void);
int process2(void);
int process3(void);
void signal_callback(int signo);
void signal_handling(void);
void sem_down(int semid, int semnum);
void sem_up(int semid, int semnum);

char work = 1, quit = 0;
char inter_snd = 0, inter_rcv = 0;
struct sembuf semstruct;
int sem23, sem12, mem;
char *message;
int res[3];

static const char *fifoname[] = { "1fifo2", "2fifo3" };

static
void main_quit(int n)
{
    printf("%s(): signal %d\n", __func__, n);
    kill(res[0], S1);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("[G] Launching\n");

    signal(SIGINT, main_quit);
    signal(SIGTERM, main_quit);
    // creating FIFO
    printf("[G] Creating FIFO... ");
    res[0] = mkfifo(fifoname[0], 0644);
    res[1] = mkfifo(fifoname[1], 0644);
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1))
    {
        perror(ERR);
        unlink(fifoname[0]);
        unlink(fifoname[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf(OK);

    // create two semaphores and set values
    printf("[G] Creating semaphores... ");
    sem12 = semget(READ, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    sem23 = semget(WRITE, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0644);

    if ((sem23 == -1) || (sem12 == -1))
    {
        perror(ERR);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf(OK);

    printf("[G] Initializing semaphores values... ");
    semctl(sem12, 0, SETVAL, 0);
    semctl(sem12, 1, SETVAL, 1);
    semctl(sem23, 0, SETVAL, 0);
    semctl(sem23, 1, SETVAL, 1);
    printf(OK);

    // creating shared memory
    printf("[G] Reserving shared memory... ");
    mem = shmget(MEM_ID, MEM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    message = (char *)shmat(mem, 0, 0);

    if (mem == -1 || message == 0)
    {
        perror(ERR);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf(OK);

    if ((res[0] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        process1();
        printf("Returned from process1() - exiting\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((res[1] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        process2();
        printf("Returned from process2() - exiting\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((res[2] = fork()) == 0)
    {
        process3();
        printf("Returned from process3() - exiting\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("[G] Building process tree... ");
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1) || (res[2] == -1))
    {
        perror(ERR);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf(OK);
        printf("[G] P1[pid]: %d, P2[pid]: %d, P3[pid]: %d\n", res[0], res[1], res[2]);
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("[G] PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);

    printf("[G] Deleting FIFO... ");
    res[0] = unlink(fifoname[0]);
    res[1] = unlink(fifoname[1]);
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1))
        perror(ERR);
    else
        printf(OK);

    printf("[G] Freeing shared memory... ");
    res[0] = shmdt((char *)message);
    res[1] = shmctl(mem, IPC_RMID, 0);
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1))
        perror(ERR);
    else
        printf(OK);

    printf("[G] Deleting semaphores... ");
    res[0] = semctl(sem23, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
    res[1] = semctl(sem12, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
    if ((res[0] == -1) || (res[1] == -1))
        perror(ERR);
    else
        printf(OK);

    printf("[G] Ending...\n");
    return 0;
}

int process1(void)
{
    char tab[100];
    FILE *fifoh;

    signal(S1, signal_callback);
    signal(S2, signal_callback);
    signal(S3, signal_callback);
    signal(S4, signal_callback);

    fifoh = fopen(fifoname[0], "w");
    setbuf(fifoh, NULL);

    printf("[P1] Ready.\n");
    while (fgets(tab, sizeof(tab), stdin) != 0)
    {
        if (work)
        {
            sem_down(sem12, WRITE);
            printf("[P1] Sending: %s", tab);
            fprintf(fifoh, "%s", tab);
            sem_up(sem12, READ);
        }
        else
            printf("[P1] Ignoring line because work is zero: %s", tab);
        signal_handling();
    }
    fclose(fifoh);
    printf("[P1] Ending...\n");
    sem_up(sem12, READ);    // Crucial
    return 0;
}

int process2(void)
{
    char tab[100];
    FILE *fifo_in, *fifo_out;

    printf("[P2] Ready.\n");

    fifo_in = fopen(fifoname[0], "r");
    fifo_out = fopen(fifoname[1], "w");

    setbuf(fifo_out, NULL);
    setbuf(fifo_in, NULL);

    signal(S1, signal_callback);
    signal(S2, signal_callback);
    signal(S3, signal_callback);
    signal(S4, signal_callback);

    do
    {
        if (work)
        {
            printf("[P2]: Waiting on semaphore sem12/R\n");
            sem_down(sem12, READ);
            printf("[P2]: Proceed on semaphore sem12/R\n");
            if (fscanf(fifo_in, "%s", (char *)tab) != 1)
            {
                printf("[P2]: EOF\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("[P2]: Signalling semaphore sem12/W\n");
            sem_up(sem12, WRITE);
            printf("[P2]: Proceeding semaphore sem12/W\n");
            printf("[P2] Received \"%s\" with length %zu.\n", tab, strlen(tab));
            printf("[P2]: Waiting on semaphore sem23/R\n");
            sem_down(sem23, WRITE);
            printf("[P2]: Proceed on semaphore sem23/R\n");
            fprintf(fifo_out, "%zu\n", strlen(tab));
            printf("[P2]: Signalling semaphore sem23/W\n");
            sem_up(sem23, READ);
            printf("[P2]: Proceeding semaphore sem23/W\n");
        }
        else
            printf("[P2] Looping: work is zero\n");
        printf("[P2]: signal handling\n");
        signal_handling();
        printf("[P2]: signal handling done\n");
    } while (!quit);

    fclose(fifo_in);
    fclose(fifo_out);
    printf("[P2] Ending...\n");
    sem_up(sem23, READ);    // Crucial
    return 0;
}

int process3(void)
{
    FILE *fifo_in;
    int count;

    printf("[P3] Ready.\n");

    signal(S1, signal_callback);
    signal(S2, signal_callback);
    signal(S3, signal_callback);
    signal(S4, signal_callback);

    fifo_in = fopen(fifoname[1], "r");
    setbuf(fifo_in, NULL);

    do
    {
        if (work)
        {
            printf("[P3]: Waiting on semaphore sem23\n");
            sem_down(sem23, READ);
            if (fscanf(fifo_in, "%d", &count) == 1)
                printf("[P3] Received: %d as the length.\n", count);
            else
            {
                printf("[P3] Failed to read an integer\n");
                break;
            }
            sem_up(sem23, WRITE);
        }
        else
            printf("[P3] Looping: work is zero\n");
        printf("[P3]: signal handling\n");
        signal_handling();
        printf("[P3]: signal handling done\n");
    } while (!quit);
    fclose(fifo_in);
    printf("[P3] Ending...\n");
    return 0;
}

void signal_handling(void)
{
    if (inter_snd > 0)
    {
        printf("PID %d: Signal received...\n", (int)getpid());

        semstruct.sem_op = -3;
        semop(sem23, &semstruct, 1);

        *message = inter_snd;
        inter_snd = 0;

        semstruct.sem_op = 3;
        semop(sem12, &semstruct, 1);

        printf("Sending to other processes\n");
        kill(0, S4);
    }
    else
        printf("PID %d: inter_snd = %d\n", (int)getpid(), inter_snd);

    if (inter_rcv)
    {
        inter_rcv = 0;

        semstruct.sem_op = -1;
        semop(sem12, &semstruct, 1);

        switch (*message)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Quitting...\n");
            quit = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Stopping...\n");
            work = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Starting...\n");
            work = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("There's garbage in memory :/..\n");
        }
        semstruct.sem_op = 1;
        semop(sem23, &semstruct, 1);
    }
    else
        printf("PID %d: inter_rcv = %d\n", (int)getpid(), inter_rcv);
}

void signal_callback(int signo)
{
    printf("%sSignal %d in PID %d\n", SIGNAL, signo, (int)getpid());
    switch (signo)
    {
    case S1:
        inter_snd = 1;
        break;
    case S2:
        inter_snd = 2;
        break;
    case S3:
        inter_snd = 3;
        break;
    case S4:
        inter_rcv = 1;
        break;
    }
}

void sem_down(int semid, int semnum)
{
    semstruct.sem_flg = 0;
    semstruct.sem_num = semnum;
    semstruct.sem_op = -1;
    do
    {
        errno = 0;
        semop(semid, &semstruct, 1);
    } while (errno == EINTR);
}

void sem_up(int semid, int semnum)
{
    semstruct.sem_flg = 0;

    semstruct.sem_num = semnum;
    semstruct.sem_op = 1;
    semop(semid, &semstruct, 1);
}
```

Note the two `sum_up()` calls marked 'crucial'; they are indeed crucial.  Also note that the input operations are error checked; that too is crucial.  If you don't check that they worked, you miss the EOF indications.  Always, but *always* check that the I/O operations worked correctly.

With that code, a sample run was:

```
$ ./semshm
[G] Launching
[G] Creating FIFO... [ OK ]
[G] Creating semaphores... [ OK ]
[G] Initializing semaphores values... [ OK ]
[G] Reserving shared memory... [ OK ]
[G] Building process tree... [ OK ]
[G] P1[pid]: 36545, P2[pid]: 36546, P3[pid]: 36547
[P2] Ready.
[P3] Ready.
[P1] Ready.
[P3]: Waiting on semaphore sem23
[P2]: Waiting on semaphore sem12/R
absolutely-ineffable-twaddle-for-onward-transmission
[P1] Sending: absolutely-ineffable-twaddle-for-onward-transmission
PID 36545: inter_snd = 0
PID 36545: inter_rcv = 0
[P2]: Proceed on semaphore sem12/R
[P2]: Signalling semaphore sem12/W
[P2]: Proceeding semaphore sem12/W
[P2] Received "absolutely-ineffable-twaddle-for-onward-transmission" with length 52.
[P2]: Waiting on semaphore sem23/R
[P2]: Proceed on semaphore sem23/R
[P2]: Signalling semaphore sem23/W
[P2]: Proceeding semaphore sem23/W
[P2]: signal handling
PID 36546: inter_snd = 0
PID 36546: inter_rcv = 0
[P2]: signal handling done
[P2]: Waiting on semaphore sem12/R
[P3] Received: 52 as the length.
[P3]: signal handling
PID 36547: inter_snd = 0
PID 36547: inter_rcv = 0
[P3]: signal handling done
[P3]: Waiting on semaphore sem23
[P1] Ending...
Returned from process1() - exiting
[P2]: Proceed on semaphore sem12/R
[P2]: EOF
[P2] Ending...
Returned from process2() - exiting
[P3] Failed to read an integer
[P3] Ending...
Returned from process3() - exiting
[G] PID 36545 exited with status 0x0000
[G] PID 36546 exited with status 0x0000
[G] PID 36547 exited with status 0x0000
[G] Deleting FIFO... [ OK ]
[G] Freeing shared memory... [ OK ]
[G] Deleting semaphores... [ OK ]
[G] Ending...
$
```

I've not worked out how much of the code could be eliminated — but my suspicion is that 'quite a lot' is an accurate statement.  The semaphore operations are really not necessary; the processes would block correctly on the file streams anyway.  I'm not convinced that the shared memory helps at all, either.  And I'm not convinced that `work` is helping very much, but it might conceivably do something useful under signal handling.  Note that it is not shared between processes (it is private to each process), so changes made to `work` by one process only affect that process, not the other processes.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. About unused variables etc. - that's what's left after many attempts to repair the code, sorry for that. Also, sorry for misspelling. I've added your code as the actual version of a program. Uncommenting `union senum` is not necessary now, as it's not used in program. Before I was using it as an argument in semctl. Also in my question I tried to better explain what am I getting and what I want to get as output. I hope it will be clear now. And again, thanks for all thar effort.

Comment: @JayL: See the (major) update.  Remember to test I/O operations for success.  Remember to release processes blocked waiting on a semaphore.  Rewrite the code to avoid semaphores (they aren't necessary).  Review whether the shared memory is relevant and remove that too if it is not.  That will significantly reduce your program size.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've already helped me so much, but if I may, I'd like to ask some questions. Could you explain to me, why this additional two `sem_up()` are crucial? They're outside loop, I don't get it. Also, I see that still I must send a message after sending a signal, then it's served. Am I doing something wrong or is it correct way?

Comment: Remove them (comment them out), rebuild and rerun.  Indicate EOF to process 1; what happens? Without the `sem_up()`, the other two processes end up waiting on their semaphores for an 'up' that never comes.

Comment: I' not sure what you want as signal handling behaviour.  If it doesn't do what you want, (a) define clearly what is supposed to happen, and (b) implement the code to make it work. Comment: when building a program like this, do it in stages rather than all at once.  Get the basic synchronous activity working correctly and then add the asynchronous signal handling code that does whatever else you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I get it. About signal handling, it should work like that - SIGINT simply ends program. So after recieving signal all processes should quit, main process should clean everything that was made and that's it. No additional actions required. SIGUSR1 should freeze program where it is (but basically I might say that it should stop program from reading STDIN). SIGUSR2 should unfreeze it (or just allow reading from STDIN again). And that's about it.

Comment: For SIGINT, only the parent process needs a handler.  The handler could remove the two FIFOs, the shared memory and the semaphores and exit with a message.  The other processes will simply exit (abnormally) when they get the interrupt.  You needed to explain the SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 usage in the question.  You probably need the 3 child processes to go into suspended animation ([`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) or [`sigpause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigpause.html)) on receipt of SIGUSR1.

Comment: You should print the PID of the controlling process, which may also need to relay SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2 to the children.  You also have to think about what happens if one child is signalled directly and goes into suspended animation while the others think they should be active.  It probably all works out OK — the active processes get blocked on a semaphore that isn't signalled because the process in suspended animation isn't paying attention to it.

Comment: About signals, all that I was told to do was to handle quitting, stopping and resuming, without further explanation, that's why I explained it so briefly. But maybe I wasn't clear enough about it. That's the problem when someone wants to do all at once, like I did. Anyway, big thanks for all your help, I'll try to handle this from here. :)

Comment: That is a very good attitude; if only more people were willing to "try to handle this from here"…